# Is there a way to see the top apps across all categories?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps, freeware

Is there a way to see some stats about the top apps in the Android Market across all categories?

The [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps) gives me some top paid and free apps per category.  How do I get the overall stats?

Answer (score 2):

[AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/apps/popular/) can give top apps overall and by cateogry.  It also has filters for Free, Paid, New, Updated and Price Reduced.

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question. I think he's looking for stats/metrics on the apps in general. Not how to filter them.

Comment: Good point.  I see where you're going and I may be completely off on this one.  Since the second part suggests the only problem with android.com is that there's no "all categories" option, I went with the interpretation that it is about top apps, not other stats.

Answer (score 2):

This [site](http://www.androlib.com/appstats.aspx) gives stats on the App Market in general, as well as distributions of ratings and downloads.