# Where can I find official statistics of most downloaded android app in play market?

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see the top apps across all categories?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1799/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-top-apps-across-all-categories)

Where can I find official statistics of most downloaded android app in play market? I would like to check which app in google market was most downloaded? Age wise, Geneder wise, Country wish, device wish, I know Android Developer Console gives statistics about the app I uploaded. But I would like to have some berif statistics about good apps/most downloaded apps in google play.

I can see lot of third party blogs - sorting n rating apps and prearing TOP 10, TOP 50 kind of list. but I can see its not official or proven.

Comment: There is no official way. See appbrain.com